# Issues running web application(.NETangular) in local host

Tags: .net, angular, web-config, hosting, iis-8

hosted the application on local IIS   and unable to run the application. I am getting an error saying page cannot be loaded. Did anyone encounter this issue? Have been struggling with it so any leads will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Expecting to run the application in local IIS, changed application and system configuration to run the application

Comment: You will have to describe from how you developed this application (from which VS project template for example). Problems might come in every steps and that's rather normal.

Comment: We need more information to analyze your problem, what is your application and what operations have you tried? What is the detailed error message?